# big-o and big-omega related to big-theta recursion

Tags: big-o

Let's suppose that a recursive formula is a big-o(n^2), and at the same time a big-omega(n^2). Does this imply that the recursion is a big-Theta(n^2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the long story short: the answer is **Yes, it does**. See proof below.

Though everybody have heard about big-o notation lets recall what exactly does these notations mean with a help of [Introduction to Algorithms](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/). For a general case it is said *Ο(g(n))*, *Ω(g(n))*, *Θ(g(n))*, but we will consider yours.

### *Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)*

*Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)* notation defines a *set of functions* for each of which the following statement holds: There exists such positive constants *c* and *n<sub>0</sub>* that *0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cn<sup>2</sup>* holds for all *n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>*.

So *f(n)* is just a function from *Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Examples *13n*, *-5*, *4n<sup>2</sup> + 5*. All these pertain to *Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

### *Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)*

*Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)* notation defines a *set of functions* for each of which the following statement holds: There exists such positive constants *c* and *n<sub>0</sub>* that *0 ≤ cn<sup>2</sup> ≤ f(n)* holds for all *n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>*.

So *f(n)* is just a function from *Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)*. Examples *n<sup>4</sup> + n - 1*, *3<sup>n</sup>*, *n<sup>2</sup> - 12*. All these pertain to *Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

### *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*

*Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)* notation defines a *set of functions* for each of which the following statement holds: There exists such positive constants *c<sub>1</sub>*, *c<sub>2</sub>* and *n<sub>0</sub>* that *0 ≤ c<sub>1</sub>n<sup>2</sup> ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>n<sup>2</sup>* holds for all *n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>*.

Again *f(n)* is just a function from *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)*. These are its representatives *n<sup>2</sup>/2 + 3*, *5n<sup>2</sup>*.

### Proof

I bet saying that a recursive formula is a big-o(n^2), and at the same time a big-omega(n^2) you meant there is a function (lets call it) *f(n)* pertaining to 
*Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)* and *Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

From *Ω(n<sup>2</sup>)* we have existence of *c<sub>1</sub>* that *c<sub>1</sub>n<sup>2</sup> ≤ f(n)* holds. From *Ο(n<sup>2</sup>)* we have existence of *c<sub>2</sub>* that *f(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>n<sup>2</sup>* holds. Consequently we have existence of *c<sub>1</sub>* and *c<sub>2</sub>* that *c<sub>1</sub>n<sup>2</sup> ≤ f(n) ≤ c<sub>2</sub>n<sup>2</sup>*, that is exactly what *Θ(n<sup>2</sup>)* is about.