# Is O(mn) in O(n^2)?

Tags: time-complexity, linear-algebra

Simple question. Working with an m x n matrix and I'm doing some O(mn) operations. My question is if O(mn) is in O(n^2). Looking at the Wikipedia on big O I would think so but I've always been pretty bad at complexity bounds so I was hoping someone could clarify.

Comment: some math basics tells that mn and n^2 comparison depends on m

Answer (score 3):

O(mn) for a `m x n` matrix means that you're doing constant work for each value of the matrix.

O(n^2) means that, for each column, you're doing work that is O(# columns). Note this runtime increases trivially with # of rows.

So, in the end, it's a matter of if `m` is greater than `n`. if m >> n, O(n^2) is faster. if m << n, O(mn) is faster.

Answer (score 2):

`m * n` is O(n<sup>2</sup>) if `m` is O(n).

I assume that for matrix you probably will have `m` = O(n) which is the number of columns while `n` is a number of rows. So `m * n` = O(n<sup>2</sup>). But who knows how many columns your matrix will have.

It all depends on what bounds does `m` have.

Have a look at [definition of O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35780618/big-o-and-big-omega-related-to-big-theta-recursion/35782465#35782465).

Comment: You mentioned that `m * n` is O(n^2) if `m` is O(n). So, my question is what if  `m` is O(n) and `n` is constant, then isn't the complexity of `m * n` be O(n)?

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 if `m` is O(n) and `n` is constant, then m = O(n) = O(1), which, incidentally, is O(n^2)

Comment: @Dhruvil21_04 yes, that is correct. If `m` is constant, then the time complexity of the whole thing is `O(n)`. If we expect both `m` and `n` to have the potential to grow towards infinity, then the time complexity is `O(n^2)`.